# Tcl/Tk : How to create progressbar along with running code?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

```
proc foo {} {
    # do something
    # sleep for 5sec
    # do something
    # sleep for 5sec
    # do something
}
```

I want as soon as we enter foo, progressbar should appear and running horizontally,
along with that foo code should also be running,
and as everything in foo finishes, progressbar should show 100% horizontally and disappear .

How to do that?

Comment: Please try out building an example yourself. Then you can post a question if you have a specific issue with your code

Comment: Do you want a GUI progress bar or a progress bar using text printed in a terminal?

Comment: I want gui progressbar

Comment: Start with a progress bar widget. There are some tricky aspects to using it though, and I've not time to write things up properly for a few hours...

Answer (score 1):

The widget you're looking for is a [`ttk::progressbar`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_progressbar.htm) (Tcl) or [`tkinter.ttk.Progressbar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#progressbar) (Python). You'll need to decide whether to use it in determinate or indeterminate mode and stuff like that.

There's one key tricky thing about using a progress bar: *you **need** to keep the event loop running while you're displaying it.* This means you need to either put the work in a separate thread or call `update` periodically. Both options have their tricky aspects:

1. When using a separate worker thread, that thread *must not* touch the GUI at all. Instead, it has to send messages to the GUI thread asking it to do the update.
2. When using periodic `update` calls (once every quarter second or so is usually enough) you need to be *very* careful to not recursively enter full event loop processing (see [the TkDocs page on the event loop](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/eventloop.html) for a discussion). This often involves doing things like disabling buttons while the processing is going on.

Were you instead after a progress bar in a terminal, those are comparatively simple because you don't have to manage an event loop; the terminal itself will do that for you.

Comment: If you don't keep the event loop going, you get weird graphical artefacting when you move the window containing the bar, or expose it after having something else shown on top, or change its size. There are a whole load of events that need to be handled for those to work right; *Tk does that for you, but only if there is an event loop running.*

Comment: sir, can u please write the code for doing same. I wouldn't get how to write code for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good idea of the time it takes to do what you have to do you can use the after command to update the progress bar at regular intervals.

```
# pop up progress bar for a calibration that takes 20 seconds
toplevel .progress
label .progress.calib -text "Calibrating ..."
ttk::progressbar .progress.bar \
  -variable ::progress \
  -length 300
grid .progress.calib
grid .progress.bar
wm geometry .progress +180+180

#
# wait 20 seconds and update the progress every 0.5 s
#
set wait_time 20000

# use a variable to wait until the progressbar is complete
after 20100 "destroy .progress"

# create updates every 0.5 second
for {set i 500} {$i <= $wait_time} {incr i 500} {
  after $i "set ::progress [expr $i*100/$wait_time]"
}

# do your stuff in less than 20 seconds
...
```

Comment: It doesnot show the progress running in progressbar while it is doing that stuff,

Comment: It is meant for a task of a specific timeinterval, for example starting another executable in background, that can not update the progressbar itself